# PHP foreach iterate twice instead of once

Tags: php

I have a question regarding the foreach function in php:

At the moment I have:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

$x=array("one","two","three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"); 

foreach ($x as $value)
  {
    echo $value . "<br />";
  }
?>
```

Which outputs:

```
one
two
three 
four
five
six
seven
eight
```

But how do I make a foreach loop iterate twice instead of once so that I get:

```
two
four 
six 
eight
```

Is this even possible? Or is it better to just use a for loop instead?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: would recommend to use `for` and has an increment of 2 instead of `foreach`.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean to step over every other entry? You should just use a for loop:

```
for($i = 1; $i < count($x); $i += 2)
{
    echo $x[$i] . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
    $i=1;

    $x=array("one","two","three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"); 

    foreach ($x as $value) {
        $i++;
        if($i%2==0){
          continue;
        }
      echo $value . "<br />";
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: surely this would get stuck after the first output? `$i` would become 2, then won't ever increase as the `$i++` is after the continue?

Comment: Nick, Thanks for pointing out the mistake, i have edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

If by "iterate twice" you mean "skip odd entries":

```
$odd = FALSE;
foreach ($x as $value)
{
    $odd = !$odd;
    if($odd){
        continue;
    }

    echo $value . "<br />";
}
```

(If you choose to use foreach you need to count yourself.)

Comment: Why would you do this instead of using a `for` loop?  Seems really wasteful to me.

Comment: This is just a tool, use it to your discretion. foreach is bad to perform position-based operations and for is bad to loop associative arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
$cnt = 0;
foreach ($x as $value)
{
  $cnt++;
  if ($cnt % 2 == 1) continue;
  echo $value . "<br />";
}
```

I would like to bring this for @GordonM
using `for` is only work assuming the array is in sequential index order,
an array such as

```
 array(2=>'one', 1=>'two', 4=>'three' ...)
```

will drag you to hell

Comment: Why would you do this instead of using a `for` loop?  Seems really wasteful to me.

Comment: True, but the OP's example was based on a uniformly-indexed array.  You could just do `array_values` or `while {(each ($array)) && ($data = each ($array)) {}` for cases when dealing with out-of-order or associative arrays (which the OP didn't ask about).

Comment: OP actually asking a foreach solution. As mentioned, assuming a sequentially indexed array is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you want.

```
$t=count($x);
for($i=0;$i<$t;$i++){
   if($i%2==0 && $i>0){
      echo $x[$i]."<br>";
   }
}
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$x=array("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"); 
$i=2;
foreach ($x as $value) {
     if( ($i % 2)==0 ) {
        echo $value . "<br />";
     }
    $i++;
  }
?>
```