# Step inside foreach

Tags: php, foreach

How to do something every 5 (for example) cycles inside foreach?

I'm add `$i++` How to check it by step?

Comment: with the Modulus operator % ... ($i % 5) == 1 ...

Comment: use Modulus http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP foreach iterate twice instead of once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072015/php-foreach-iterate-twice-instead-of-once)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use modulo to determine offset.

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($array as $a) {
   $i++;
   if ($i % 5 == 0) {
       // your code for every 5th item
   }

   // your inside loop code
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, don't use the modulo operator.  Start `$i` at 5; `if (--$i == 0) { $i = 5; // do other things`

Comment: What is more faster? Modulo in foreach OR loop in for?

Comment: If you want to do anything other on each record then foreach with modulo. But if you want to process only every fifth record use answer posted by Justin Niessner - the first one.

Answer (score 7):

Unless you're doing something separately in each iteration, don't.

Use a for loop and increment the counter by 5 each time:

```
$collectionLength = count($collection);

for($i = 0; $i < $collectionLength; i+=5)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Otherwise, you can use the modulo operator to determine if you're on one of the fifth iterations:

```
if(($i + 1) % 5 == 0) // assuming i starts at 0
{
    // Do something special this time
}
```

Comment: `count` every loop iteration is generally bad idea

Comment: That should be `$i+=5` in the for loop in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for($i = 0; $i < $items; $i++){
    //for every 5th item, assuming i starts at 0 (skip)
        if($i % 5 == 0 && $i != 0){
            //execute your code
        }
    }
```